# Need to edit data using combobox's data in php

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

i am fetching few data to edit this. in edit page all the data is showing from database. but i want to add combobox with data on that edit page.

i have below code for database connecting.

```
<?php
$event_id=0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['event_id']) && $_REQUEST['event_id']>0)
{
$event_id = $_REQUEST['event_id']; 
}
if($event_id>0)
{
$username="root";
$password="1amShaw0n";
$database="shawon_logindb";
    $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
mysql_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM shawon_logindb.event_table WHERE event_id = '$event_id'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

also in edit page i am showing the data to edit using below code.

```
<form name="edit_form" method="post" action="event_save_edited_data.php" />
<input type='hidden' name='event_id' value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['event_id']; ?>" />
<table>
<tr>
<th width="194" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row"><div align="center" class="style13">
<div align="center">Event Type:</div>
</div></th>
<td width="500"><input type="text" name="event_type" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['event_type'])?$_POST['event_type']:isset($row[1])?$row[1]:''; ?>" ></td>
</tr>
```

But i want to edit this using combobox's data. Please let me know the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to echo the whole statement, using the correct type as text is not a combobox and use empty instead of isset.

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['event_type'])) 
        echo "<select name='event_type' value='$_POST['event_type']'>";
    else if(empty($row[1]))
        echo "<select name='event_type' value='$row[1]'>";
    else
        echo "<select name='event_type' value=''>";
?>
```

Then your options to edit and close it at the bottom:

```
<option value="type_1">type_1</option>
<option value="type_2">type_2</option>
<option value="type_3">type_3</option>
```